# How to convert DataFrame to Dataset[CaseClass]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

i'm facing a problem trying to convert my Dataframe into a Dataset so that i can run  Kmeans clustering algorithm.My code is the above

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Dataset, Encoder, Encoders}

case class MyCase(sId: Int, tId:Int, label:Double, sAuthors:String, sYear:Int, sJournal:String,tAuthors:String, tYear:Int,tJournal:String, yearDiff:Int,nCommonAuthors:Int,isSelfCitation:Boolean
                  ,isSameJournal:Boolean,cosSimTFIDF:Double,sInDegrees:Int,sNeighbors:Array[Long],tInDegrees:Int,tNeighbors:Array[Long],inDegreesDiff:Int,commonNeighbors:Int,jaccardCoefficient:Double)

val men = Encoders[MyCase]

val ds: Dataset[MyCase] = transformedTrainingSetDF.as(men)
```

Trying to do this, i get the following error:

> Error:(208, 23) object Encoders does not take type parameters.
>
> val men = Encoders[MyCase]

Comment: Where do you define the case class? Do you enter the lines to `spark-shell` or are they part of a Spark app?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an explicit encoder for converting a DataFrame (= a Dataset of `Row`s) to a Dataset of `MyCase`. So, the easiest way to fix the issue with `val men = Encoders[MyCase]` is simply to remove it.

---

Let's assume the following case class `Person`:

```
case class Person(id: Long, name: String)
```

It should really be as follows, but it's not needed at all.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders
Encoders.product[Person]
```

With that put aside, fix the `as` part. It should use `as` that takes a type not an object (they are different in their purpose).

```
val ds: Dataset[MyCase] = transformedTrainingSetDF.as[Person]
```

And you're done.

Comment: Where does `Person` come from?

Comment: @matanster It's just a sample case class. Added it to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Encoders.product` method for case classes as per `Encoders` documentation:

> An encoder for Scala's product type (tuples, case classes, etc).

Try changing it as follows:

```
val men = Encoders.product[MyCase]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok , i think i found the reason i got the error. I should have written

```
case class MyCase(sId: Int, tId:Int, label:Double, sAuthors:String, sYear:Int, 
sJournal:String,tAuthors:String, tYear:Int,tJournal:String, 
yearDiff:Int,nCommonAuthors:Int,isSelfCitation:Boolean,                         
isSameJournal:Boolean,cosSimTFIDF:Double,sInDegrees:Int,sNeighbors:Array[Long],tInDegrees:Int,tNeighbors:Array[Long],inDegreesDiff:Int,commonNeighbors:Int,jaccardCoefficient:Double)
```

Before

```
object Test {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
```

Comment: What Spark version do you use? Was this the only change in your Spark app or were the other recommended changes (incl. mine) needed too?

Comment: after using .product as @JacekLaskowski said and i moved my code above object

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone is trying to transform Dataframe's row to a case class and using:

`case class Person(id: Long, name: String)`

`val ds: Dataset[MyCase] = transformedTrainingSetDF.as[Person]`

But only get an error saying "Unable to find encoder for type...."

an `import scala3encoders.given` solves the issues for me...